# How to declare a variable as Equatable?

Tags: swift, swift5

```
var myDict: [String: Any]
```

But in my case `Any` isn't actually `Any`. It's either `Int` or `String`. So how I should declare my `var myDict` in a way to show it's `Equatable`?

```
var myDict: [String: Any] where Any: Equatable //it doesn't compile
```

Or something like this :)

Comment: It's meaningless in Swift to say that you have an array (or dictionary) of `Equatable`s... `Equatable` is not a kind of object; it's rather like a "property" of a type, which can be equated to their own kind, but not between different kinds. The question, what do you want to do with this dictionary later

Comment: @New Dev Compare. myDict didSet { guard newValue != myDict alse return }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it can be Int or String, then use an IntOrString union enum type. An IntOrString union enum type can be made equatable (you don't even need code, you just declare it):

```
enum IntOrString : Equatable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}
```

Thanks to conditional conformance, a dictionary of type `[String: IntOrString]` will now be Equatable.

Comment: recently I've been trying to push novices more towards protocols and polymorphism. I fear that they're not as familiar to the draw backs of enums, and end up having fragile code with switches all over that breaks everytime a new case is added

Comment: Fair enough, feel free to give an alternate solution.

Comment: Done. I hope it doesn't go over the heads of new users though. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a protocol that models the grouping of your types, and extending those types to conform to that protocol.

For example, suppose the purpose of these ints or strings was to populate a cell in a table. You would do something like this:

```
/// some example type that models a table cell
class Cell {
    var value: String
    
    init(value: String) { self.value = value }
}

protocol CellRepresentable {
    func populate(in: Cell)
}

extension Int: CellRepresentable {
    func populate(in cell: Cell) {
        // Don't ever format numbers for user-consumption like this
        // Use a NumberFormatter. This is for demo use only
        cell.value = String(self)
    }
}

extension String: CellRepresentable {
    func populate(in cell: Cell) {
        cell.value = self
    }
}

let myDict: [String: CellRepresentable] = [
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": "value 2",
    "key3": 3,
]
```

The key is to design the protocol to represent an abstraction (in this case, something that can be represented by a cell), and not be too closely modeled to a concretion (such as the storage detail of the representable thing being either an `Int` or `String`).

The benefit to this approach is that it's really simple and extensible. You ask these values to do whatever it is you want them to do. If you used an enum instead, you couldn't do that, you would be forced to constantly write `switch` cases, and you'd have to determine the right behavior of each `case` in every scenario.

Using polymorphism like this means that you can easily add support for `Bool`, without needing to edit every `switch` statement in your program. Polymorphism just "takes care of it".

Comment: You lost me. The problem was to make two dictionaries Equatable by making their Value types Equatable. How does this do that?

Comment: Ah, I missed that aspect of the original question. The trick, roughly speaking, is to not use equatable. Because adding `Equatable` to  a protocol makes it a `CellRepresentable`, it turns it into a PAT that prevents it from being used in as an existential like here. But `Equatable` doesn't really mean what most people means. It's very specific to comparing two values of type `Self`, and not just equating things of potentially different types (which is what's really needed here). So you use something like an `isEqual(to:)` function instead See Rob Napier's:  https://youtu.be/DXwJg0QTlZE?t=2260